# C algorithm for calculating norm/inner product

Tags: c, algorithm, math

I have a need to check if a point in R^2 lies in a circle of relatively large radius r (up to 10^5).  Obviously I would normally just compare the inner product to r^2, but this is in an embedded environment and this isn't going to work on int32_t values that are large enough since the quadratures will overflow the type (max 32 bit types).

Possible solutions:

I could manually kludge a 64 bit product out of two 32 bit ints (probably what I'll end up doing).

I could divide everything by 10 (or any value) then do the usual inner product comparison, but I loose precision.

I could try to check inside an n-gon inscribed in the circle, but that is a lot of calculation, tables, etc. and I still loose precision.

Is there an algorithm that is typically used for this sort of thing?

Comment: What's the range of r?

Comment: Do you care more about worst-case timing or average time for each point? Is code size a concern?

Comment: @EOF I would rather have a limit on worst-case timing, but if there is an average time algorithm that has significantly lower typical time, then that might work.  I might be able to filter out slow values if I knew ahead of time.

Comment: @Jabberwocky Its maximum possible value is 100000 (100k)

Comment: If you're trying to decide whether `x^2 + y^2 < r^2` is true, you can test if either `x` or `y` is greater than `r` fairly quickly, and whether *both* `x` and `y` are less than `r/sqrt(2)`. Depending on how your `x`, `y` and `r` are distributed, this could be a useful fast test.

Comment: You could do a crude initial test with a simple bounding box. If the point is outside the box, it's outside the circle.

Comment: You can handle `r` up to 65535 with 32-bit math. For `r` between 65536 and 100000, divide the values by 2. The trick is to round odd numbers correctly. If you round `r` down and the coordinates up, and the point is still in the circle, then the point is definitely in the circle. On the other hand, if you round `r` up, and the coordinates down, and the point is outside, then it's definitely outside. So that leaves the rare case where you're dealing with odd numbers, and the point is neither definitely inside or outside the circle.

Comment: When dealing with large values, don't compute `x^2 + y^2 <= r^2`, because the addition could overflow even when `x<r` and `y<r`. Instead compute `x^2 <= r^2 - y^2`. As long as `y <= r` the subtraction is guaranteed to work.

Comment: @user3386109 The subtraction is simple and clever, thanks!

Comment: Are you truly concerned in precision loses by discarding 10 parts in 4 billion? really?

Comment: @LuisColorado I wouldn't say concerned, but I would need to document it and my reasons for doing it for the next poor sap to encounter my code, and I need to explain somewhere to the client what the reduction in precision means for them, etc etc. And heaven forbid there is ever a future bug that leads to an error in this part of the functionality - this code will get blamed whether or not it's valid.  By just kludging a 64bit value, I don't have to document anything extra since the precision is the same as any other discretely implemented mathematical formula.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm afraid computing the 64-bit results is the simplest solution. Check if your compiler can generate efficient inline code for this:

```
int check_distance(int x, int y, int r) {
    return (long long)x * x + (long long)y * y <= (long long)r * r;
}
```

If the generated code seems too slow, you can add a test to check if 64-bit operation is required. Assuming `x`, `y` and `r` are positive, here is a solution using unsigned arithmetics and exact width types from `<stdint.h>`:

```
int check_distance(uint32_t x, uint32_t y, uint32_t r) {
    if (x <= 46340 && y <= 46340 && r <= 0xffff) {
        /* 32-bit unsigned expression does not overflow */
        return x * x + y * y <= r * r;
    } else {
        return (uint64_t)x * x + (uint64_t)y * y <= (uint64_t)r * r;
    }
}
```

Notice the constant 46340 which is `floor(sqrt(pow(2, 31)))`: If both `x` and `y` are greater than this value, `x*x + y*y` will exceed 2<sup>32</sup>.

Here is an alternative with a quicker test, but that will fall back to 64-bit operation for slightly smaller values:

```
int check_distance(uint32_t x, uint32_t y, uint32_t r) {
    if ((x | y | r) <= 0x7fff) {
        /* 32-bit unsigned expression does not overflow */
        return x * x + y * y <= r * r;
    } else {
        return (uint64_t)x * x + (uint64_t)y * y <= (uint64_t)r * r;
    }
}
```

Then if you **really** don't want to use the compiler's 64-bit arithmetics, you can write the computation explicitly. Considering the range of `x`, `y` and `r` specified as `<= 100000`, shifting the values right 2 bits keeps `x` and `y` below 46340:

```
int check_distance(uint32_t x, uint32_t y, uint32_t r) {
    if (x <= 46340 && y1 <= 46340 && r1 <= 0xffff) {
        /* 32-bit unsigned expression does not overflow */
        return x * x + y * y <= r * r;
    } else {
        /* shift all values right 2 bits to keep them below 46340 */
        uint32_t x0 = x & 3;
        uint32_t y0 = y & 3;
        uint32_t r0 = r & 3;
        uint32_t x1 = x >> 2;
        uint32_t y1 = y >> 2;
        uint32_t r1 = r >> 2;
        uint32_t x2_lo = x0 * (x0 + x1 * 8);
        uint32_t y2_lo = y0 * (y0 + y1 * 8);
        uint32_t d2_lo = x2_lo + y2_lo;
        uint32_t d2_hi = x1 * x1 + y1 * y1 + (d2_lo >> 4);
        uint32_t r2_lo = r0 * (r0 + r1 * 8);
        uint32_t r2_hi = r1 * r1 + (r2_lo >> 4);
        return d2_hi < r2_hi || (d2_hi == r2_hi && (d2_lo & 15) <= (r2_lo & 15));
    }
}
```

Finally, shifting values by 5 bits allows for numbers up to 1000000:

```
int check_distance(uint32_t x, uint32_t y, uint32_t r) {
    if (x <= 46340 && y1 <= 46340 && r1 <= 0xffff) {
        /* 32-bit unsigned expression does not overflow */
        return x * x + y * y <= r * r;
    } else {
        /* shift all values right 5 bits to keep them below 46340 */
        uint32_t x0 = x & 31;
        uint32_t y0 = y & 31;
        uint32_t r0 = r & 31;
        uint32_t x1 = x >> 5;
        uint32_t y1 = y >> 5;
        uint32_t r1 = r >> 5;
        uint32_t x2_lo = x0 * (x0 + x1 * 64);
        uint32_t y2_lo = y0 * (y0 + y1 * 64);
        uint32_t d2_lo = x2_lo + y2_lo;
        uint32_t d2_hi = x1 * x1 + y1 * y1 + (d2_lo >> 10);
        uint32_t r2_lo = r0 * (r0 + r1 * 64);
        uint32_t r2_hi = r1 * r1 + (r2_lo >> 10);
        return d2_hi < r2_hi || (d2_hi == r2_hi && (d2_lo & 1023) <= (r2_lo & 1023));
    }
}
```

All of the above versions produce exact results for the specified ranges. If you do not require exact result, you can just shift the values to bring them within the proper range and perform the 32-bit computation:

```
int check_distance(uint32_t x, uint32_t y, uint32_t r) {
    while (x > 46340 || y > 46340 || r > 0xffff) {
        x >>= 1;
        y >>= 1;
        r >>= 1;
    }
    /* 32-bit unsigned expression no longer overflows */
    return x * x + y * y <= r * r;
}
```

Comment: Thanks!  Yea, that's actually what I'm doing now.  It's not bad - it just feels like there should be something easier.  But then math is a cruel mistress sometimes.

Comment: @TrivialCase: Did you look at the assembly code generated for the above function? The processor should have a 32x32 -> 64 multiply opcode

Comment: Yes unfortunately it just overflows a 32, so I will just stick with cobbling together a 64 but value from two 32s split into 16 bit words.

Comment: chqrlie's answer is as good as it gets for checking "within a circle."  A potential optimization is to check if `-r <= x <= r` and `-r <= y <= r`, before checking`x*x + y*y <= r*r`.  You would have to benchmark this to see if it makes a difference.  With full retail optimizations turned on, it might not make any difference.

Comment: It's going to be very difficult to beat the compiler in generating assembly with the above code snippet.

Comment: @selbie This would be true for a common architecture with, say, gcc support.  However, this is an in-house mcu and an in-house compiler (I actually end up implementing much in assembly due to compiler limitations as is).  As a result, the architecture team works on compiler optimization, but it is far from good - and there is little overhead damage in implementing this myself.  Also that's the only choice if I want to use 64 bit values... so that's what I'll be doing.

Comment: @chqrlie Thanks for the elaboration in your edit.  Unfortunately, the compiler never gives any sort of 64bit value and there are no 64 bit opcodes for this microcontroller.  Instead, code like your first example simply truncates to the lower 32 bits and moves on.  As a result, the programmer needs to implement 64bit handling themselves by controlling upper and lower 32bit word.  The fun of in-house silicon/compilers/etc.

Answer (score 2):

The maximum radius you can have, using the premises you have described is `100000`, which leads to a squared modulus of `10 000 000 000`, which requires (as all numbers are positive) `35` bit integer (of `unsigned` square radius) to be represented.

Based on these premises, and the fact that you have no easy way to get 64bit integers, and having quite low extra bits, we can scale the results four bits in norm (two bits in the source coordinates) to achieve full capacity to handle upto `100000` coordinates in a 32bit unsigned integer.

In my first edition of this answer, I assumed using only one shift in the coordinates was enough to handle the full set of values (two bits in the calculated norm), and losing 1 bit of precision was considered, but I was wrong and one extra bit was needed. It is needed to shift the results at least three bits to hold the full set of inputs, so I decided to scale the coordinates two bits, and so the results would be scaled by four.  As I decided also to always scale, and return the fraction of a square unit as an integer ranging from `0` to `15` (in sixteenths of a square unit).  So you will achieve exact results by comparing first the integer parts of the two points and use the fractional parts, in case the integer parts match.  This makes the computation and the meaning of the results returned back more coherent than earlier, and gives you complete exactitude with integer coordinates.

You requested a working implementation, so I have posted one for you below:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>

/* calculate the square of a divided by four number and
 * accumulate the fraction (in sixteenths of a square unit)
 * into the reference pointed by frac_p.  */
uint32_t
square_of_div16(uint32_t x, int *frac_p)
{
    /* we use (IP + FP)^2 = IP^2 + 2*IP*FP + FP^2 */

    uint32_t int_part    = x >>  2;                /* divide by four */
    uint32_t frac_part   = x & 0x3;                /* mod 4 */
    uint32_t int_result  = int_part  * int_part;   /* square of IP */
    int      frac_result = frac_part * frac_part;  /* square of FP */
    uint32_t mixed_prod  = int_part  * frac_part;  /* IP*FP */

    int_result  +=  mixed_prod >> 1;
    frac_result += (mixed_prod & 1) << 3;
    if (frac_result >= 0x10) { /* carry process */
        int_result  += frac_result >> 4;
        frac_result &= 0x0f;
    }
    if (frac_p) *frac_p += frac_result; /* accumulate */
    return int_result;
}

/* this calculates the squared norm scaled to one sixteenth
 * of the original coordinates (scaled by one fourth).
 * The ref_fraction pointer is a reference of a variable to
 * accumulate the fraction sixteenths of a square unit.  If
 * you are not interested in the fraction value, you can just
 * pass NULL as parameter. */
uint32_t
norm_scaled(uint32_t x, uint32_t y, int *ref_fraction)
{
    int fraction = 0;
    uint32_t result = 0;

    result += square_of_div16(x, &fraction);
    result += square_of_div16(y, &fraction);

    if (ref_fraction)
        *ref_fraction += fraction; /* the excess */

    return result;
}

/* TEST MAIN PROGRAM.  Just input pairs of coordinates in the
 * same line (separated by spaces) and calculate the squared
 * norm of the vector, scaled by 1/16 (accumulating the
 * fraction of the value in 1/16s of a square unit in the
 * location referenced.  This is done using double floating
 * point numbers and uint32_t integers. */
int main()
{
    char line[256];
    while (fgets(line, sizeof line, stdin) != NULL) {
        int x = 0, y = 0, fraction = 0;

        sscanf(line, "%u%u", &x, &y);

        uint32_t norm_16th = norm_scaled(x, y, &fraction);

        printf("Trying (%u, %u) => %u (fraction = %d/16)\n",
                x, y, norm_16th, fraction);

        double norm_sq_16th
            = (double) x/4.0 * (double)x/4.0
            + (double) y/4.0 * (double)y/4.0;

        printf("squared norm scaled: %.8f\n", norm_sq_16th);
    }
    printf("Program finished\n");
}
```

The function `square_of_div16` calculates a scaled modulus divided by 16 of a number, so we can reuse it to calculate the squares of `x` and `y` coordinates.  The function takes a pointer frac_p to an integer variable to store the fraction part (in sixteenths of a square unit)

The function `norm_scaled` then calculates the norm, by using the `square_of_div16` function and adding both results.  The fractional part is accumulated for both calls and the result is accumulated to the referred variable by pointer `ref_fraction`.  A carry processing is done in here, to give correct results.

Finally a `main()` routine is in charge of querying the user to input pairs of coordinates and calculate the scaled norm of the resulting vector by calling the function and using the squares pithagorean formula applied to `double` values.  The results should be the same in all cases.

Comment: This is really the answer I think.  Any sane person would know that the reduction in precision is likely well within the margin for error of, say, the ADC that I am getting the coordinates from.  In my case, I am on the hook to explain to the client the reduction in precision, so I might not actually implement it this way - but this is still a very good answer.  Thanks!

Comment: Your approach is fine, but you should "normalize* the fraction in `square_of_div16` so the resulting `fraction` is always <= 15: use `int frac_result = frac_part * frac_part + *frac_p;`. The test `if (frac_result >= 0x10)` is probably more costly than always performing the carry propagation. Also you did not post the function that checks if the point is within the circle.

Comment: @chqrlie as you see, i do normalization (i call it carry processing) after I add the numbers.  Before is nonsense, as I'm accumulating the value of several sums.  I do all at once in the last part, after all the sums have been done.  The cost of making a bit shift against a full integer multiplication doesn't need to be demonstrated (what you do in your comment)  The right shift is a division by 16 while the and mask is a remainder calculation.  Do you really think your recommendation is going to be more efficient? don't believe so.

Comment: @chqrlie, you can see that the last operation I do with the `fraction` is to mask it with `fraction &= 0x0f;`, so it is going always to be a number in the range 0 to 15.  The adding done with the external reference is not normalized, as any normalization should be done in the external procedure (it is possible that the calling process is doing several sums and want to _normalize_, after all sums have been done)  This is so for two reasons: 1) to improve efficiency (only one carry proc is done at the end) and 2) overflowing an `int` with sums of numbers in the range 0 to 15 is not probable.

Comment: The last operation in `square_of_div16()` is not masking `fraction` with `0x0f`, it is `if (frac_p) *frac_p += frac_result; /* accumulate */` which may produce a value in `*frac_p` larger than `15`. Adding the current of `*frac_p` to `frac_result` is harmless and cheap. and the final operation becomes `*frac_p = frac_result;`. Obviously you would need to remove the possibility to pass a null pointer for `frac_p`. With this approach the result is always normalized, which makes the comparison much simpler and avoids the pitfall of forgetting to perform a final normalisation.

Comment: I don't understand where I hinted to use a multiplication or a division in place of shifting and masking... I wrote that you could remove the test on `frac_result` and always perform `int_result  += frac_result >> 4; frac_result &= 0x0f;` which are cheaper than a mispredicted test.